# Different computation on 32 bit and 64 bit OS

Tags: c++, c

Does a computation like multiplying two double values -> -329.0000 * 0.000000 gives result -0.000000 in 32 bit and 0.000000 in 64 bit?

Comment: It *should* return the same value, [per IEEE-754 rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) - assuming the environment works as so. Both single (32-bit) and double (64-bit) floating types usually exist in [non-embedded] 32 and 64-bit environments.

Comment: I just tried it, and got the same result on both. If you've tried it and gotten different results, please update your question with that information. If you haven't tried it, why not?

Comment: You've asked this question slightly different ways a few times now, and from what I've seen, gotten some excellent answers and advice explaining how floating point arithmetic works.  I'm still clueless as to what exactly motivates your question, or how the previous answers fail to answer your question.

Comment: You should not ask further questions about this until you can provide a [self-contained compilable example](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: The second variable may display as "0.000000", but it does not have the numeric value of zero.  It is a small value near zero that your method of printing is insufficient.  `printf()` it with "%e" to display significant digits.

Answer (score 3):

You have already asked about issue behind this question in four previous questions, and you have been informed that the cause of what you are seeing is that you have a small negative value that is not zero (or negative zero) but is displayed as “-0.000000” because of the format specification used to display it. The value is smaller (closer to zero) than -0.0000005, so it is rounded to a **display** of all zeros. **The display is not the actual value**.

Print the value with the `%g` specifier, and you will see that it is not zero.

Comment: The result of `-329.0000 * 0.000000` is not some small non-zero value. Mathematically, it's exactly zero. In IEEE arithmetic, the result is negative zero; printing with `%g` shows `-0`, and it compares equal to `0.0`. (This would be clearer if the OP provided actual code.)

Comment: @KeithThompson: It is apparent from the OP’s other questions that they are **not** multiplying -329.0000 by 0.000000. They have some `double` object that contains a tiny non-zero value but is displayed as “0.000000” due to formatting, and this has led them to mistakenly believe that it is 0. Similarly, the product of multiplying this tiny value by -329 is a tiny negative value that is displayed as “-0.000000” but that is not actually zero. Two of the OP’s other questions show a branch taken that indicates the value is not zero (including negative zero).